# 2 Include code into 1 line php sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with the following code. How do i put 2 included files into 1 line include?
I already tried it like the code below but nothing is shown (blank page). It should show the url.

- Url: theme/default/main/index.php (it would be)
- application-sql-realtime.php = (should show 'default' or anything else when user changing their themes template it connect to sql)

```html
    <?php include('./theme/<?php include_once("config/application-sql-realtime.php");?>/main/index.php');?>
```

[Refer image for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsREt.png)

Comment: When you get a blank page/ or a 500 check your error log. The first `?>` closes the PHP processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include_one` returns `boolean`

Maybe can be like this:

```
<?php
$theme = exec("php config/application-sql-realtime.php");
include("./theme/{$theme}/main/index.php");
?>
```

But I think you better put it in some class/function

```
<?php
// inside application-sql-realtime.php you declare a function to return theme name eg: getThemeName
include("config/application-sql-realtime.php");
$theme = getThemeName();
include("./theme/{$theme}/main/index.php");
?>
```

Comment: the first it working another one i didnt get how to declare but thanks for your time

Comment: Just wrap your code inside `application-sql-realtime.php` with function and instead of `echo` use `return`. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 0):

Make a class with a static or non static method to retrive the value you need (e.g. 'default'). Then you can implement this value in your string to include the first file. Following an example of a static method call:

```
<?php
$val = EgClass::getPathPart();
include('./theme/'.$val.'/main/index.php');
?>
```